# C#: How to htttps get request with bearer token in header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, dynamics-365, erp

Hello everyone my name is Taniguchi.

I've tried retrieving an entity from Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations and i did it on postman but now i having difficulties in asp.net core I was able to get the token but when i try to retrieve the entity the response gives me a html and this html leads me to the Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Page.
My code:
`

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        const string environmentsUri = "https://trial-0z4qfj.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/data/PartyContacts";

        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(environmentsUri).Result;

        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

what am i doing wrong ? do i need to authenticate again ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the Token you receive is not correct/complete.
I remember I faced the similar issue, I would request you to follow [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-access-token-for-dynamics-365-single-tenant-server-to-server-authentica/) post and try to receive Token as shown This shall help you solve your issue.

In addition I would recommend you use Organizaiton service with Webapi/Access Token. It will give you native library usage and you could query crm easily.

[Try this blog for Orgservice](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/10/obtain-organizationservice-using-application-user-in-dynamics-365/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are only using the parameter `accessToken` instead of the variable value. Depends on how you declared `accessToken` ofc. The rest seems fine.

Try:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.accessToken);
```